# Equivalence of definitions of minimal polynomial of a linear transformation $T$ over a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $T\in \operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$. Then $V$ has a $K[x]$-module structure via the operation defined as $f(x)v=f(T(v))$.

Using this we can know a lot about the structure of the $K[x]$-module.

The problem I have is this: for a linear operator $T\in \operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$, I have three definitions for the minimal polynomial of $T$:

1. The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $T$ is the monic polynomial with the smallest degree such that $m(T)=T_{0}$ where $T_{0}$ is the zero transformation.
2. The minimal polynomial of $T$ is the largest invariant factor in the decomposition of $V$.
3. The minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial that generates the ideal $I=\operatorname{ann}(V)$.

How can I prove the equivalence of all these definitions?

Comment: Did you forget to state that $V$ is finite dimensional?